# How do I Split a string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Suppose there is a string named as (ai-somename-someid) and it is stored in say

```
$x='ai-somename-someid'
```

Now I want to extract (somename)from the given string and pass it into another variable by using split(I am using the below script)

```
$y = $x.split("-")   
$y
```

It is giving me the output as

```
ai  
somename   
someid
```

but I would like to have only

```
somename
```

as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or using the split operator.  This is really about picking the 2nd element of an array.  The count starts at 0.

```
'ai-somename-someid' -split '-' | select-object -index 1
somename
```

-split on the left side will split on whitespace.

```
(-split 'ai somename  someid')[1]
somename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass y[1] as a variable name for someone.

```
$x= "ai-somename-someid"
$y =  $x.split("-")
$y[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of way you can do that :
If you only want one item this is the most straight forward way to do it. Simply cut your string and reference the id of the element you want to save.

```
$x="ai-somename-someid"
$y=$x.split("-")[1]
```

or you could do this instead if you are interested in keeping the other parts :

```
$x="ai-somename-someid"
$z,$y,$v=$x.split("-")
```

In this exemple $z will have ai, $y somename and $v someid.

If you are only interested in keeping some of the resulting string you can do this :

```
$x="ai-somename-someid"
$z,$y,$null=$x.split("-")
```

In this exemple $z will have ai, $y somename and everything after that goes to the trash.